# Homestead DB config

Tags: database, config, mamp

Is it possible to have multiple local database configurations? I have just setup homestead but I work in a team who use MAMP, and MAMP username password is **root** whereas homestead uses **homestead** and **secret**.

So if I change the details it works fine for homestead but then breaks for MAMP users.

```
'local' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'craft',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root'
)

'local' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'craft',
    'user' => 'homestead',
    'password' => 'secret'
)
```

Is there a way to have local set both to be compatible with homestead and MAMP at the same time?

Comment: If you define your environment variables following this guide, it is easy to maintain this using the same repository: https://nystudio107.com/blog/multi-environment-config-for-craft-cms

Comment: Could you add this as an answer, Lazy Pirate? Add a bit more information (rather than just the link), and you've got my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this if statement at the bottom of your **config/db.php** file

```
// If a local config file exists, merge
if (is_array($localConfig = @include(CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH . 'local/db.php')))
{
    // does our default config already have a local key?
    if(array_key_exists('local', $config))
    {
        // If so, merge what's in our local/db.php
        $config['local'] = array_merge($config['local'], $localConfig);
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, just set as our 'local' key
        $config['local'] = $localConfig;
    }
}

// return our $config back to craft
return $config;
```

Then create a **config/local/db.php** with your homestead configuration

```
<?php
/**
 * Local-only Database Configuration
 *
 * The returned array will be merged ONLY with the in-built 'local' array in config/db.php,
 *
 * Usage: duplicate file as `config/local/db.php` and cutomise values below.
 */

return array(
    'server'    => 'localhost',
    'user'      => 'homestead',
    'password'  => 'secret',
    'database'  => 'example'
);
```